# Goodness of fit using characteristic function

Tags: goodness-of-fit, characteristic-function

When assessing goodness of fit of a model, one can use, for example, a Q-Q plot of empirical vs theoretical distributions. But how does one perform a GoF assessment when there is no closed form distribution (e.g., from alpha-stable family)?

Since a characteristic function always exists (even when a pdf does not), is it possible to use it to perform a GoF test? How would one go about doing this? Would one take an FFT of the data to get an empirical characteristic function and then somehow compare it to the theoretical one (a CF-CF plot)?

Are there any equivalents for likelihood-based tests but based on the characteristic function?

Comment: The CDF always exists and is much simpler to compute and work with.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. Yes, the CDF does always exist, but in some cases (like alpha-stable distributions) only a CF is available in a closed from (and using elementary functions), so I am wondering if this can be used in GoF tests.

Comment: There are indeed some papers on that, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167947309002308